# Sharepoint 2019 on-premise - customise modern theme

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, branding, 2019

Currently moving to SP2019 on premise.
I want to brand a new modern site. I would like to change the theme colour - which I guess is a new theme, add a logo - I don't think this is a big deal, change the default font and hide the SharePoint text at the top.
I believe the modern pages are not customizable but I do believe the themes can be customized?
This platform is completely new to me - any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SharePoint 2019 on-premise, creating and applying custom themes is quite same as other SharePoint on-premise versions.

Please check below URLs for the same:

1. [Overview of themes in SharePoint Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/sites/themes-overview).
2. [Use composed looks to brand SharePoint sites](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/use-composed-looks-to-brand-sharepoint-sites)

To Hide the SharePoint default text or anything, you can use **SPFx Application Customizer**.

See my answer at: [What is the best practice for getting JS and CSS files into a SharePoint Modern Page?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/277352/what-is-the-best-practice-for-getting-js-and-css-files-into-a-sharepoint-modern/277353#277353)

Comment: Thanks Ganesh - I'm going to enjoy getting to know this new platform. Thanks for the overview - this is a great starting point. I'll get back with other question as I begin to dabble.

Answer (score 1):

Currently in SharePoint server 2019 modern site,you could change the logo,customize the theme.please refer to the following article for details:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/customize-your-sharepoint-site-320b43e5-b047-4fda-8381-f61e8ac7f59b

Change the default font and hide the SharePoint text at the top will use SharePoint framework extension application customizer to inject the CSS to your modern SharePoint pages.

Following sample tells you how to inject the CSS:

https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-extensions/tree/master/samples/react-application-injectcss

Comment: Thanks Julie - I'm going to give these a go. I haven't had any experience with the spfx app - ignorance here - do I need any particular software to create extensions?

Comment: You can use Visual Studio or your own custom development environment to build SharePoint Framework solutions.Here is an article for your reference:https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/52603.sharepoint-2019-sharepoint-framework-spfx-development.aspx