# How to remove default Save and Cancel button on Customized SharePoint form through PowerApps

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, list-form, powerapp, powerapps-forms

I have customized the SharePoint list form using PowerApps.

On the new form and edit form, we have custom button which submits the opened form. We need to remove or disable the default "Save" and "Cancel" buttons which are by default available over the top bar of the PowerApps form of list new/edit form.

So, please guide me on this thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is no SharePoint or Power Apps out of the box way to hide the Save & Cancel buttons.

There are similar Power Apps Ideas, you can Vote here:

1. [Hide Default SharePoint buttons like Save & Cancel](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Apps-Ideas/Hide-Default-Sharepoint-buttons-like-Save-amp-Cancel/idi-p/135261)
2. [SharePoint Custom Form - allow designer control of Save/Cancel buttons](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Apps-Ideas/SharePoint-Custom-Form-allow-designer-control-of-Save-Cancel/idi-p/126150)

**Workaround**:

You can create a [SPFx application customizer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/build-a-hello-world-extension) to inject the CSS & hide the list form buttons by checking the current page URL (which should match with list URL).

More on injecting custom CSS & JS: [What is the best practice for getting JS and CSS files into a SharePoint Modern Page?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/277352/what-is-the-best-practice-for-getting-js-and-css-files-into-a-sharepoint-modern/277353#277353)

---

You can also try the suggestions given in below article (Not tested by me):

[HIDE Save and Cancel button on PowerApps Form](https://techwizard.cloud/2019/09/15/hide-save-and-cancel-button-on-powerapps-form/)

Comment: Hi Kailash, did it help you in any way? If yes, Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). It will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily.