# Hide Save and cancel button

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, powerapp, spfx-extensions, powerapps-forms

I have a SharePoint list and a Power Apps form for the items of this list.

I have created a Save button on my PowerApps form because I have flows to run before the save.

So I would like to hide the Save and Cancel native button:

[image: This buttons!]

I didn't find JS or CSS solutions, can somebody help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to hide these buttons from Power Apps customized list forms using out of the box way.

**Possible Workarounds**:

1. If you just want to run a flow on button submit, you can run the flow in **OnSave** property of **SharePointIntegration** before *SubmitForm(SharePointForm1)*.

   [image]
2. Use SPFx Application customizer:

   You can create a [SPFx application customizer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/build-a-hello-world-extension) to inject the CSS & hide the list form buttons by checking the current page URL (which should match with list URL).

   You can find more details in my answer at: [How to remove default Save and Cancel button on Customized SharePoint form through PowerApps](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/293682/how-to-remove-default-save-and-cancel-button-on-customized-sharepoint-form-throu)