# Hide left menu for lists

Tags: sharepoint-online, navigation, modern-experience, quick-launch, team-sites

I can not figure this one out.

How do I remove this menu?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things you can try:

**Disable Quick Launch**:

1. Go to site settings
2. Select **Navigation Elements**
3. Uncheck **Enable Quick Launch**
4. Click **OK**

[image]

**Remove all navigation links**:

1. Click on **Edit** at the bottom of left navigation
2. Remove all links one by one
3. Click **Save**

**Output**:

[image]

---

**Note**: It will hide left navigation from all places & not just **lists**.

If you want to hide the left navigation temporarily when you are viewing list items/data, you can use the **Expand content** option at the top:

[image]

It will hide [SharePoint app bar](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/02/24/introducing-a-sharepoint-app-bar-that-features-global-navigation/), left navigation, site title & logo temporarily until you again **Collapse content** using the same option.

---

**Update from comments**:

The quick launch (left navigation) is hidden on lists as well for me:

[image]

Comment: Hi @Fredrik, Did you try this? Is it working for you?

Comment: Hi and thanks for your answer! I have tried these. The settings for Enable Quick Launch is off and I have no links in the menu, the settings where like this already. This left menu is visible on all lists for this site but hidden on all pages.

Comment: It is working for me in lists as well (check screenshot in updated answer). Did you activate any publishing feature or something on your site?

Comment: Yes, that sounds familiar! I that do be able to share the top menu across subsites, got that working. I also did that to be able to move pages from one subsite to another if I remember correct, did not get working though.

Comment: If you don't need the site feature anymore, can you please try the above steps after **deactivating** the site feature?

Comment: I do need those as I create new subsites from time to time and what those to have the same top menu. Can we find any work around?

Comment: I am not sure if there is any out of the box workaround for this. However, you can try creating a SPFx application customizer to [inject the custom CSS](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/277352/what-is-the-best-practice-for-getting-js-and-css-files-into-a-sharepoint-modern/277353#277353) on modern pages & apply custom CSS to hide the left-navigation.

Comment: Hi @FredrikSundlöf, Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it helped you in any way.

Answer (score 1):

The above answer will hide it on that whole site. If you just want to hide the left nav bar on the single list page do the following:

1: Click settings and "Edit Page"

2: Add new web part to the page

3: Choose the script editor web part:

4: Insert the following into the script editor

```
<script>
<style>
#sideNavBox { DISPLAY: none }
</style>
</script>
```

Click the gear icon in the top right:
[image]

Then click edit page and this will appear on the list:
[image]

Comment: There is no `Edit Page` option on default list page. Also, OP is using modern experience where you cannot add script editor web part.

Comment: I just realized it is a modern experience, but you are able to edit and add a web part to the classic experience, see my edited answer.

Comment: I don't think OP will want to move to classic experience, just for hiding the left navigation. OP will loose all the modern capabilities, [SharePoint app bar](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/02/24/introducing-a-sharepoint-app-bar-that-features-global-navigation/), rich UI, etc. Also, Script editor web part is not available by default. Administrator need to enable the custom script first to use it.