# Can we remove the SharePoint word from the upper banner for all our sharepoint sites

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, spfx, modern-experience, administration

We have a SharePoint online tenant, and we need to remove the word SharePoint from all the upper banners for all the sites, so first question is this possible per site, then is this possible for all the sites at once?

Here is the SharePoint word I am talking about:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is **no** SharePoint out of the box settings to show/hide the "SharePoint" title in header.

---

**Workaround (Not recommended)**:

You can inject custom CSS on SharePoint online modern pages using SPFx application customizer & hide the SharePoint title from header.

Check below references for more information:

1. [How can I include the same JS and CSS files on multiple SharePoint Modern Page?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/277352/how-can-i-include-the-same-js-and-css-files-on-multiple-sharepoint-modern-page/277353#277353)
2. [Customize SuiteBar on modern SharePoint online site](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint/customize-suitebar-on-modern-sharepoint-online-site/m-p/1019106)
3. [Trimming the Suite Bar + Ribbon on Modern SharePoint Sites in Office 365](https://thomasdaly.net/2018/05/14/trimming-the-suite-bar-ribbon-on-modern-sharepoint-sites-in-office-365/)

**Note**: DOM manipulation & CSS customizations are **not recommended** by Microsoft and some of your customization may break if Microsoft changes HTML element id/classes in new release updates.

Comment: so you mean the 3 links you provided can achieve what i am looking for but they are not recommended ?

Comment: In short you have to inject custom CSS to hide the SharePoint title (DOM manipulation). To inject CSS on all modern pages in a site, you can use SPFx application customizer. And doing DOM manipulation or injecting custom CSS is not recommended by Microsoft.