# Hiding Office 365 Ribbon in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, master-page, modern-experience, sitepages

Is it possible to create Master page in Office 365 SharePoint? If yes, how to do that?

I need to hide the office 365 ribbon (blue color) and remove below menu like New, Send To, Promote, Page Details and Analytics.

How to Achieve this task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Custom master pages are currently not supported for "modern" pages.

You can find supported/unsupported customizations in below documentations:

1. [Customizing "modern" site pages](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/modern-experience-customizations-customize-pages)
2. [Customizing "modern" team sites](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/modern-experience-customizations-customize-sites)
3. [Branding your SharePoint site](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/branding-sharepoint-online-sites-modern-experience)

---

There is no SharePoint out of the box option to hide office 365 ribbon at the top.

**Workaround (Not recommended)**:

You can inject custom CSS on SharePoint online modern pages using SPFx application customizer & hide the office 365 ribbon.

Check below references for more information:

1. [How can I include the same JS and CSS files on multiple SharePoint Modern Page?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/277352/how-can-i-include-the-same-js-and-css-files-on-multiple-sharepoint-modern-page/277353#277353)
2. [Customize SuiteBar on modern SharePoint online site](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint/customize-suitebar-on-modern-sharepoint-online-site/m-p/1019106)
3. [Trimming the Suite Bar + Ribbon on Modern SharePoint Sites in Office 365](https://thomasdaly.net/2018/05/14/trimming-the-suite-bar-ribbon-on-modern-sharepoint-sites-in-office-365/)

**Note**: DOM manipulation & CSS customizations are **not recommended** by Microsoft and some of your customization may break if Microsoft changes HTML element id/classes in new release updates.

---

To hide few of the page options like Promote, New, etc. you can manage this using SharePoint out of the box permissions.

To hide these options from pages, grant visitor/read only access to users on site pages so that these options will be visible only to users with Edit or higher permissions.

Comment: Thank you Ganesh!