# How to disable app bar on SharePoint online modern site

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, modern-experience, administration, sharepoint-app-bar

I would like to disable app bar on SharePoint online modern site with PowerShell command, not able to perform the same due to an error. Neither CSS scripting is also working for me.

Any assistance or help would be really appreciated. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: which version of SPO PowerShell are you using?

Comment: version: 16.0.8715.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot disable the SharePoint app bar permanently. However, you can temporarily disable the SharePoint app bar in your tenant using PowerShell until **March 31, 2022**.

Seems like you are using older/wrong version where required cmdlet is not available. Follow below steps to disable SharePoint app bar:

1. Download the latest version of [SharePoint Online PowerShell](https://docs.microsoft.com/powershell/sharepoint/sharepoint-online/connect-sharepoint-online).
2. Connect to SharePoint admin tenant site using:

```
Connect-SPOService -Url https://<tenant>-admin.sharepoint.com
```

3. Then, run the following command with administrator privileges:

```
Set-SPOTemporarilyDisableAppBar $true
```

**Reference**: [Introducing a SharePoint app bar that features global navigation](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/02/24/introducing-a-sharepoint-app-bar-that-features-global-navigation/)

---

**Alternate solution**:

Inject custom CSS using SPFx application customizer to hide the SharePoint app bar. You can use the CSS like:

```
div#sp-appBar {
    display: none !important;
}
```

**Note**: DOM manipulation & CSS customizations are **not recommended** by Microsoft and some of your customization may break if Microsoft changes HTML element id/classes in new release updates.

Comment: Thank you so much for your support i'm able to do with latest version of SharePoint online management shell, one more query - can we disable top bar which shows 'SharePoint' with blue color time.

Comment: No, you have to do that using custom CSS only. Check [this thread](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/297914/hiding-office-365-ribbon-in-sharepoint/297915#297915) for more information.

Comment: should we consider this advice obsolete as for today?

Comment: You cannot hide it using PowerShell since March 31, 2023. Check the "Reference" link in my answer. Alternate solution is still possible but not really recommended.