# Change the Button colors, Font Color & Font Family for our SharePoint online modern UI

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, development, modern-experience, theme

We have the following modern UI:

[image]

Where we are trying to get the below UI, which have the following changes: Button color is different, Font Family is different & Font size/color is different , as follow:

[image]

So is this something we can achieve in SharePoint online modern UI? and how?

Comment: Do you want to change the color & font across all pages/lists on site or for just this one list view?

Comment: @GaneshSanap across all pages and views

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in SharePoint online using below two ways:

1. **SharePoint site theming - recommended**:

You can create a custom theme for your SharePoint site & apply custom styles and colors to sites.

Not sure if you will be able to achieve all your requirements (like specific font-size) using custom themes but this is the recommended solution by Microsoft for for applying custom styles to sites.

Check below Microsoft documentations for more information:

- [SharePoint site theming](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/site-theming/sharepoint-site-theming-overview)
- [SharePoint site theming: JSON schema](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/site-theming/sharepoint-site-theming-json-schema)
- [SharePoint site theming: PowerShell cmdlets](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/site-theming/sharepoint-site-theming-powershell)

2. **Injecting custom CSS using SPFx application customizer - Not recommended**:

You can inject custom CSS on SharePoint online modern pages using SPFx application customizer & change the styling of HTML elements using their HTML id's & classes.

Check below reference for more information:

1. [How can I include the same JS and CSS files on multiple SharePoint Modern Page?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/277352/how-can-i-include-the-same-js-and-css-files-on-multiple-sharepoint-modern-page/277353#277353)

**Note**: DOM manipulation & CSS customizations are **not recommended** by Microsoft and some of your customization may break if Microsoft changes HTML element id/classes in new release updates.

Comment: i do not want to inject any custom CSS for the reasons you mentioned.. but can you advice more where i can find examples and documentations on what i can achieve using SharePoint site theming? and how to create these?

Comment: Check documentation links in my updated answer above.

Comment: Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it helped you in any way.