# Remove white space from left and right inside our SharePoint modern home page

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, modern-experience, modern-pages, communication-site

We have added a new modern page as the home page for our modern communication site, as follow:

[image]

but currently on the left and right sides of the page they is a lot of white spaces, so is there a way to remove/minimize this white space?

Comment: No OOTB settings to manage space on modern pages. Are you seeing this space on all pages in site or just this page?

Comment: @GaneshSanap on all pages inside the modern communication site

Comment: I believe this is because of responsive nature of modern pages & it cannot be changed using out of the box capabilities. Check with other users having small resolution devices & see if they are also seeing the same space at left/right (I guess not).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are seeing these spaces because of responsive nature of modern pages & it ***cannot*** be changed using out of the box capabilities of SharePoint online.

Check with other users having small resolution devices & see if they are also seeing the same space at left/right (I guess not).

---

**Not recommended**: You might be able to reduce the space by removing margin/padding of specific `div` elements on the page by injecting custom CSS on pages using SPFx application customizer. But, it might not look good for smaller screen devices. Also, it is not recommended by Microsoft to inject custom CSS.

[How can I include the same JS and CSS files on multiple SharePoint Modern Page?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/277352/how-can-i-include-the-same-js-and-css-files-on-multiple-sharepoint-modern-page/277353#277353)