# Custom URL Link for SharePoint Site Logo

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, hyperlink, site-logo

I have an custom logo in my SharePoint Teams Site. Basically, I need it so that when users click on that logo, it directs them to a completely different link.

Right now, I can't seem to find a way to do so without it linking back to the site itself.

Here's a dummy example of the part of the page I'm referring to.

[image]

Is there an easy way to do this that doesn't involve messing around too much with site collection features / SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure etc.?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it is not possible in SharePoint Online environment using OOTB settings. By default, clicking on the site logo will always bring the user back to the home page of this site. And it's not feasible to change this setting.

**Similar thread**: [Change the URL link of the Logo shown on a SharePoint site](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/change-the-url-link-of-the-logo-shown-on-a/40de0381-38e8-4a53-bfce-95d5107e9d2d)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I saw that link. But is there any sort of workaround?

Comment: There is no OOTB/easy way. But, you can inject some custom CSS/JS using SPFx application customizer & override the default URL on site logo. Check [my answer here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/277352/how-can-i-include-the-same-js-and-css-files-on-multiple-sharepoint-modern-page/277353#277353).