# Hide copy link option in context menu

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, modern-experience, json-formatting, copylink

Since we are having issues with copy link, is there any way we can hide it?

[image]

[image]

This way we forcing users to use Copy document ID only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **cannot** hide "Copy link" option from context menu (under **...** ellipses menu) in SharePoint online modern experience using OOTB capabilities.

You have to create [SPFx extension (Application customizer) to inject custom CSS](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/277352/how-can-i-include-the-same-js-and-css-files-on-multiple-sharepoint-modern-page/277353#277353) for hiding this. However, such DOM manipulations are not recommended by Microsoft.

---

However, you **can** hide the "Copy link" option from command bar (at the top) using [JSON view command bar formatting](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/view-commandbar-formatting).

Use below JSON in **Format current view** option under **Switch view options** dropdown (where you switch the library views):

```
{
    "commandBarProps": {
        "commands": [
            {
                "key": "copyLink",
                "hide": true
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

**Output**:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

We could use SharePoint Json formatting to hide some command bar buttons.

Supported buttons:

```
'new'
'newFolder'
'newWordDocument'
'newExcelWorkbook'
'newPowerPointPresentation'
'newOneNoteNotebook'
'newFormsForExcel'
'newVisioDrawing'
'upload'
'uploadFile'
'uploadFolder'
'open'
'share'
'copyLink'
'download'
'rename'
'copyTo'
'moveTo'
'delete'
'edit'
'comment'
'editNewMenu'
'powerBI'
'powerBIVisualizeList'
'automate'
'automateCreateRule'
'automateManageRules'
'powerAutomate'
'powerAutomateCreateFlow'
'powerAutomateSeeFlows'
'powerAutomateConfigureFlows'
'aiBuilderCreate'
'aiBuilderGoto'
'aiBuilder'
'alertMe'
'newLink'
'integrate'
'manageAlert'
'powerApps'
'powerAppsCreateApp'
'powerAppsSeeAllApps'
'powerAppsCustomizeForms'
'viewDocumentUnderstandingModels'
'versionHistory'
'openInImmersiveReader'
'classifyAndExtract'
'checkOut'
'checkIn'
'undoCheckOut'
'properties'
'pinItem'
'exportExcel'
'exportCSV'
'export'
'editInGridView'
'sync'
'uploadTemplate'
'addTemplate'
'openInOfficeOnline'
'openInOfficeClient'
'addShortcut'
'pinToQuickAccess'
'unpinFromQuickAccess'
```

Tested json for your reference:

```
{
  "commandBarProps" : {
    "commands": [
      {
        "key": "copyLink",
        "hide": true
      }           
    ]
  }
}
```

Document Link:https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/view-commandbar-formatting

The another 'Copy Link' button you may need to use SPFX extension to inject CSS to hide it.