# SharePoint: how to put the box in the header area or navigation?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, modern-experience, spfx-webparts, spfx-extensions

Anyone know how can I put the box in image in the navigation area without using SPFx just CSS only.

[image]

Comment: You cannot inject css in modern pages without spfx. Also, custom css/DOM manipulations are not recommended by Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot inject custom CSS in modern pages without using SPFx.

You can use SPFx application customizer to inject the custom CSS in SharePoint online modern pages. Check more information at:

1. [How can I include the same JS and CSS files on multiple SharePoint Modern Page?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/277352/how-can-i-include-the-same-js-and-css-files-on-multiple-sharepoint-modern-page/277353#277353)

---

**Note**: DOM manipulation & CSS customizations are **not recommended** by Microsoft and some of your customization may break if Microsoft changes HTML element id/classes in new release updates.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, custom css are not supported by sharepoint modern page any more. We can only use spfx to custom the modern page. Please refer to following document

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/modern-experience-customizations-customize-sites

As a wrokaround, You can deploy [react-script-editor](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples/react-script-editor) to your tenant so you could the webpart to this page, then you could add custom CSS/JavaScript to this page.

Answer (score 0):

i already did it. I dont need spfx. i just copy the div and replace something on it

Comment: Can you explain the solution in detail? Are you doing this for single page or all pages? How you changed HTML on modern page, which webpart you used?

Comment: i used modern editor

Comment: ok, that is SPFx developed custom web part only. Glad you got it working.

Comment: Glad that you found the solution to this problem. Thanks for your sharing.