# Sharepoint header put time without spfx

Tags: sharepoint-online, header

Can any one here try to put time in header without using spfx? Is it possible to do?
Or it really need to use spfx.

Comment: Are you trying to add it on single page or all pages in site? Are you using modern experience or classic experience?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to add anything in header without SPFX Extension in Modern UI

Go through [SPFX Extension samples](https://pnp.github.io/sp-dev-fx-extensions/), here you can find out some samples which are adding some content in header.

Important: **DOM manipulation** is not recommended by **Microsoft**. As Microsoft can change html structure any time.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot inject custom JavaScript/CSS in modern pages without using SPFx.

**For single page**:

You can use Modern Script Editor web-part to add custom JavaScript/CSS code individual modern pages in SharePoint site. Below is the open source Modern Script Editor web-part created using SPFx:

[Modern Script Editor web-part](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-script-editor).

**For all pages in site**:

You can use SPFx application customizer to inject the custom CSS in SharePoint online modern pages. Check more information at:

1. [How can I include the same JS and CSS files on multiple SharePoint Modern Page?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/277352/how-can-i-include-the-same-js-and-css-files-on-multiple-sharepoint-modern-page/277353#277353)

---

**Note**: DOM manipulation & CSS customizations are **not recommended** by Microsoft and some of your customization may break if Microsoft changes HTML element id/classes in new release updates.

Answer (score 0):

Two web parts that are not available in SharePoint for Microsoft 365 modern pages are the Script editor web part and the Content editor web part. So we are unable to insert css or js script to modern page directly. We need to use spfx to create csutom webpart.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/where-are-the-content-editor-and-script-editor-web-parts-in-sharepoint-ed6cc9ce-8b2a-480c-a655-1b9d7615cdbd