# SharePoint Modern Page - Hide Edit , Analytics , Page details options

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, modern-pages, sitepages, homepage

I have to hide the New , Page Details, Analytics and Edit option to all users expected site owners.

I can't use SPFx in my site, is there any other way I can hide these bar.

Any solution would be much appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a site page with "Home" layout to remove the New, Page Details and Analytics options.

Follow this article: [SharePoint Online: Create a blank page without header & title](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/03/26/sharepoint-online-create-a-blank-page-without-header-and-title/)

If you have already created a page, you can change it's layout to "Home" using PowerShell:

```
PnPClientSidePage -Identity "MyPage.aspx" -LayoutType "Home"
```

---

You can remove "Edit" option using SharePoint permissions - grant "Read" permissions to users so that they cannot see the "Edit" option on page.

---

**Update from comments**:

There is no SharePoint out of the box way to completely hide the page tool bar. You may need to inject custom CSS to hide the complete page tool bar.

Check: [How can I include the same JS and CSS files on multiple SharePoint Modern Page?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/277352/how-can-i-include-the-same-js-and-css-files-on-multiple-sharepoint-modern-page/277353#277353)

**Note**: DOM manipulation & CSS customizations are **not recommended** by Microsoft and some of your customization may break if Microsoft changes HTML element id/classes in new release updates.

Comment: The given doesn't solve my issue.  I actually aware of this workaround , even with that we cannot hide the "New" , "page details "

Comment: If you grant "Read" access to users on site level (or site pages library level), they cannot see the "New" option as well

Comment: If you want to hide the complete page tool bar, you have to use SPFx. But, I don't think you are able to use SPFx in your site.

Comment: Yes, i Can't  user SPFx,

Comment: Then I am afraid, there is no other way. Best you can do is, use "Home" layout with "Read" permissions.

Comment: yes,  Thanks @Ganesh

Comment: done, thank you so much