# JSON command bar customization for web part possible?

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, modern-experience, json-formatting, sitepages

Is it possible to also customize command bars in web parts same as for list views?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/view-commandbar-formatting

[image]

Comment: Hi @sp00ky, did you try below solution? Is it working for you?

Comment: Hi @ganesh, as said this is clear, but not what I meant. See my commet below

Comment: Check updated answer below. Hope if helps!

Comment: Hi @sp00ky, does below updated response answers your question? If yes, Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried using below JSON in SharePoint list view formatting for command bar:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/row-formatting.schema.json",
  "commandBarProps": {
    "commands": [
      {
        "key": "new",
        "hide": true
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

It works both in SharePoint list view as well as in list web part on SharePoint site page.

**SharePoint list view**:

[image]

**List web part on page**:

[image]

---

**Update from comments**:

Unfortunately, you cannot customize site page command bar using JSON command bar formatting. There are no SharePoint default functionalities available to customize these commands.

You might be able to hide few of the options from page command bar. Check my answer at: [SharePoint Modern Page - Hide Edit , Analytics , Page details options](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/303832/sharepoint-modern-page-hide-edit-analytics-page-details-options/303834#303834)

Comment: This is clear, that the menu of the list can be also changed with view formatting feature inside of the webpart. But I want to hide the menu of the page/webpart. e.g. page details, analytics and so on.

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot customize site page command bar using JSON command bar formatting. See updated answer for possible workaround.