# Running modern 2022 native Web Components in Microsoft365/SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, modern-experience, cewp, script-webpart

I am an old CEWP user. Haven't used SharePoint in years.

For a new Online project I have been asked to explore if my team (some 50+ autistic people with distance to the labor market) can work on a Microsoft365 environment.

All I can find is blogs that require the whole React toolchain.
My team has basic HTML and JavaScript skills, I can't teach them this React voodoo, they understand native Web Components (as its basic HTML and JS skills)

Only CEWP like reference I could find is: 2019: https://spjsblog.com/modern-cewp/
But has several issues and no long maintained

**Is it no longer possible to include JavaScript in a page like this ?**

```
<script>
// comes from one CDN file
customElements.define("copy-right", class extends HTMLElement{
  connectedCallback(){
    this.innerHTML = `Copyright ACME - 2022`;
  }
});
</script>

<copy-right></copy-right>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no SharePoint out of the box web part using which you can add JavaScript to modern pages.

You have below two options:

1. If you are trying to add custom JavaScript to all modern pages, you can use SPFx application customizer to inject custom JavaScript/CSS. Follow for more information:
   [How can I include the same JS and CSS files on multiple SharePoint Modern Page?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/277352/how-can-i-include-the-same-js-and-css-files-on-multiple-sharepoint-modern-page/277353#277353)
2. If you are trying to add custom JavaScript to individual modern pages, you can use modern script editor web part

   Check this web part: [Script editor web part for modern pages](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples/react-script-editor)

---

**Note**: DOM manipulation & CSS customizations are **not recommended** by Microsoft and some of your customization may break if Microsoft changes HTML element id/classes in new release updates.

Comment: Interesting answers, where did good old CSR go... SPFX is voodoo to me as well; can't I buy an extension? If I read the second link, all I need is: _Upload .sppkg file from sharepoint\solution to your tenant App Catalog_

Comment: CSR is supported in classic experience but not in moder experience. You need to download the code from second link then [generate .sppkg package and deploy the package to app catalog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/serve-your-web-part-in-a-sharepoint-page)

Comment: Also, you can use JavaScript, jQuery, Angular, Vue.js, Knockout or any other JavaScript framework with SPFx. But you will find more examples, blogs/articles related to using react.