# Align Text and Increase Font Size of SharePoint Global Navigation

Tags: sharepoint-online, css, modern-pages, global-navigation, top-navigation

I would like to Align text to center of the global Navigation and Change the font size and color of the menu, I have tried looking for class or id from the page but somehow it links to the site navigation ms-HorizontalNavItems. How to find the class and add the styling to the Top Nav.

Global Nav in app bar

[image]

Comment: Which navigation are you talking exactly, [global navigation in app bar](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/04/04/enable-and-customize-global-navigation-in-the-sharepoint-app-bar/) OR [site navigation for team/communication site](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/09/17/new-navigation-features-for-sharepoint-team-sites/)? Can you add screenshot?

Comment: @GaneshSanap I have added the screenshot and i was mentioning about App bar above site navigation, where we edit in Hub site settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the classes by inspecting the HTML elements in browser.

You can add custom CSS to `ms-HorizontalNavItem-link` class like given below to change the font size of menu item text:

```
.ms-HorizontalNavItem-link { 
    font-size: 20px 
}
```

You can add additional styles to menu items as per your requirements.

To add custom CSS on modern pages, you have two options:

1. Use SPFx application customizer to inject CSS on all modern pages
2. Use Modern script editor web part to inject CSS on single modern page

More information about injecting CSS: [How can I include the same JS and CSS files on multiple SharePoint Modern Page?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/277352/how-can-i-include-the-same-js-and-css-files-on-multiple-sharepoint-modern-page/277353#277353)

---

**Note**: DOM manipulation & CSS customizations are **not recommended** by Microsoft and some of your customization may break if Microsoft changes HTML element id/classes in new release updates.

Comment: I use Modern script editor right now as in the screenshot I use background color blue but somehow I cannot make the Navitems to center in the Global Nav in app bar or Top Navigation

Comment: I don't think you will be able to make it center aligned by injecting custom CSS as HTML structure defined by Microsoft is different & may not support centering the content.

Comment: You may need to create your own navigation using SPFx application customizer placeholders if you want center aligned navigation.