# Can we widen the column to the left so that the full text is displayed?

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, modern-pages, quick-launch, left-navigation

Can we widen the column to the left so that the full text is displayed?

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to increase/decrease the width of left navigation? Or are you trying to see the page/list view in focus (full screen) mode?

Comment: Hi @Harris, does my reply given below answers your question? let me know if you need any clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you cannot increase/decrease the width of left navigation menu in SharePoint online modern experience.

If you are trying to view pages in focus (full screen) view, you can use "Focus mode" in SharePoint: [Introducing Focus mode for modern SharePoint pages](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/03/21/introducing-focus-mode-for-modern-sharepoint-pages/)

---

You might be able to change it using custom CSS and DOM manipulation using SPFx application customizer (for all pages) OR modern script editor (for single page).

But the DOM manipulation & injection of custom CSS/JS is not recommended by Microsoft and your customization may break in future.

Check: [How can I include the same JS and CSS files on multiple SharePoint Modern Page?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/277352/how-can-i-include-the-same-js-and-css-files-on-multiple-sharepoint-modern-page/277353#277353)