# How do I change SharePoint title font size?

Tags: sharepoint-online, title, size, font

In this case, I'm looking to change the sizing of the title "Website".

[image]

Comment: Are you using classic experience pages only? Did you add any custom coding (JS or SPFx) to add custom footer on the site? Check: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/277352/how-can-i-include-the-same-js-and-css-files-on-multiple-sharepoint-modern-page/277353?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C0.0000#277353