# Hiding Breadcrumb Navigation in Item Properties Page

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, powerapp, list-form

Wish to seek for your advice here based on facts + supporting image below:

- I have created a Prospect Management System, using Power Apps + SharePoint as base
- Due to organization policy on visibility of the prospect among sales staff, certain limitations has been applied where if the sales staff wish to view their own prospect, they need to double click the name of the prospect from the filtered list, and the item properties will be opened up via Power Apps
- We observed that in item properties page, sales staff will be able to access and view the master list via clicking on "Navigation 2" link of the breadcrumb navigation bar, which will bring them back to the master list rather than the filtered list

Question is:

- Is there a way for us to hide or disable to breadcrumb in Item Properties page? If so, how?
- Alternatively, perhaps changing or disable to link navigation in the breadcrumb?

Any other proposals are welcomed, thanks!

[image: Supporting Image of SP Item Properties Page]

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to hide/remove or disable the breadcrumb navigation on SharePoint list form using SharePoint out of the box capabilities.

However, you can use SharePoint framework (SPFx) application customizer to inject the custom CSS on the `DispForm.aspx` page of the list to hide the breadcrumb navigation.

Check my answer given here for more information about injecting custom CSS and JavaScript on SharePoint pages using SPFx application customizer: [How can I include the same JS and CSS files on multiple SharePoint Modern Page?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/277352/how-can-i-include-the-same-js-and-css-files-on-multiple-sharepoint-modern-page/277353#277353)

**References**:

1. [Build your first SharePoint Framework Extension](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/build-a-hello-world-extension)
2. [SPFx Applications Customizer CSS Injection](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-extensions/tree/main/samples/react-application-injectcss)