# Adding Scripts to the header of a SharePoint site

Tags: sharepoint-online, script, header

I am trying to add a script like this:

```
<script src="http://www.whatever.com/widget.js"></script>
```

into the header code of my SharePoint communications site. I need to call out to a script from another site.

Where can I edit the header code on a SharePoint. I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: You cannot edit the code of SharePoint modern experience sites. If you want to inject the custom JS/CSS in SharePoint, you have to use the SPFx. Check: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/277352/how-can-i-include-the-same-js-and-css-files-on-multiple-sharepoint-modern-page/277353#277353.